# google visualization datatable issue with rerunning render

Tags: google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I have a query returning the top ten most visited pages over a specific date range and it works the first time the page loads, but when the query is rerun I get the error:

```
You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView
```

Here is the code:

```
        function renderDataTable(viewID){
            var dateRange = getDateRange(),dataQuery;

         dataQuery = query({
            ids: 'ga:' + viewID,
            metrics: 'ga:pageviews,ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:entrances,ga:bounceRate,ga:exitRate',
            dimensions: 'ga:pageTitle',
            sort:'-ga:pageviews',
            'max-results':10,
            'start-date': moment(dateRange.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            'end-date':moment(dateRange.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }).then(function(results){

    var colltypes =['string','string','avgtime','string','percent','percent'],x=0,
        i=0,
        row=[],
        rows=[],
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        if(results.totalResults > 0){
            data.addColumn('string', stStats.pagetitle);
            data.addColumn('string', stStats.pagevisits);
            data.addColumn('string', stStats.duration);
            data.addColumn('string', stStats.entrances);
            data.addColumn('string', stStats.bouncerate);
            data.addColumn('string', stStats.exitpercent);

            for(x=0;x<results.rows.length;++x){
                //rows
                row =[];
                for(i=0;i<results.rows[x].length;++i){
                //format columns
                    row.push( formatTotals(results.rows[x][i], colltypes[i]));
                }
                rows.push(row);
            }
            data.addRows(rows);
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table-1-container'));
            table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
        }
        });
    }
```

the first time round the call to `new google.visualization.DataTable()` produces an object that in the console looks like:

```
gvjs_P {Vm: null, OA: "0.6", ng: Array(0), og: Array(0), Hr: null, …}
```

when I call the function again, with either exactly the same query params or different I get the error and the result from the call to the DataTable is different.

```
gvjs_R {Pm: null, IA: "0.6", Mf: Array(0), Nf: Array(0), vr: null, …}
```

this is before I have added rows or anything.. whats even more annoying I can't replicate the problem in a simple fiddle.. which means there has to be a problem with my code somewhere but I can't seem to find it.. any help would be appreciated.

ps the query function was taken from the embed api example, and it appears only to happen when there are two charts on the same page.. One is created using the embed api the other with the visualization api..

Comment: Data is being defined in the vars directly above the code line ` `if(results.totalResults > 0){`

Comment: look a little closer at the code

`var colltypes =['string','string','avgtime','string','percent','percent'],x=0,
        i=0,
        row=[],
        rows=[],
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();`
its all var

Comment: thanks, and this is the only place the chart is being drawn? not seeing any problems here...